# Allow user to order a list of selections?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think what I want to do is pretty straightforward, but it isn't for me (a newbie).

I have a list of, say, 10 services a client can purchase. I'd like the client to be able to order this list of services based on which he'd like to do first, second, third, etc.

I'm envisioning a dropdown box or checkboxes that first shows all 10 options, then eliminates the first option after the user picks one and so on.

Ideally, I'd like to have the services the user selected display in order below the dropdown (or elsewhere on the page) perhaps with additional details on the service, so he can see the order he chose at the end. It would essentially be a custom list of service implementation for that person.

I'd prefer to do this all with javascript/jquery and HTML (and CSS). Any simple ways to do this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Just an example of what I might want to do to make it more clear.

```
<select name="products" size="6"> 
<option selected>Select A Starting Product</option> 
<option value="1">Car Wash</option> 
<option value="2">Wax</option> 
<option value="3">vacuum</option> 
<option value="4">polish</option> 
<option value="5">drying</option> 
</select>
```

Based on which items the person picks from the box and in what order, a list would populate below the box with items selected in the correct order they were selected. Open to doing this with checkboxes as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not sorting exactly. You want the user to see the items/services to see in the order he/she has selected.

On the selection of any service call a javascript function and append the new service to the list in which you are showing the selected services.

```
$('#ddlServices').change(function() {
  // Append the new service to the list you are showing.
  var str = "";
  $("select option:selected").each(function () {
       str += $("div").text() + "<br/>" + $(this).text() + " ";
  });
  $("#divServices").text(str);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Again, consider I'm a newbie trying to learn by doing some practice things. Let's say this is my selection list, how would I write the js?  `<select name="products" size="6">
<option selected>Select A Starting Product</option>
<option value="1">Car Wash</option>
<option value="2">Wax</option>
<option value="3">vacuum</option>
    <option value="4">polish</option>
    <option value="5">drying</option>
</select>`

Comment: check the edited answer. "ddlServices" is id of products ddl and "divServices" is the id of div in which services will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI has a [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) component that allows list items to be sorted into different orders.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this isn't exactly the functionality I was looking for. Just edited my question with more details to explain it better

Answer (score 1):

Try [DataTables](http://datatables.net/), this will allow you to retrieve data from a database, or manually enter it, the user can then sort by all columns, and even use the search box to dynamically update.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for the [jQuery UI Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) function. Please try to do some research and testing before asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I actually have done a lot of research on this and that's why I posted the question. I've seen the sortable function and this isn't what I need. Perhaps I need to explain my requirements better.